# ¿Porqué al leer un archivo e imprimir sólo imprime posición 0?

Tags: python, python-3.7

¿Por que al leer un archivo e imprimir, sólo imprime posición 0?

Además, imprime todo el archivo, si se pone posición 1 se desborda.

```
import numpy as np

a = [3,4,6]
b = [4,6,7]

x  =  np . array ([a,b])
# usa notación entera
p . savetxt ( 'test.out',  x ,  fmt = ' % d  ' ,header="x     y     z" )
```

---

```
archivo = open("test.out")
for lineas in archivo:
    datos = lineas.split(",")
    print(datos[0])
```

---

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, estás presuponiendo que el archivo test.out tiene comas y cuando llamas
a la función:

```
datos = lineas.split(",")
```

esperas que dato sea un array y este es el error; 
si llamas a la función len

```
len(datos)
```

debajo del *split()*, podrás ver que datos solo mide uno es decir, datos solo tiene datos[0] y cuando accedes a la posición 1 no existe y se desborda.

Debes mirar el archivo de salida que se ha generado en el paso anterior para poder cambiar dicho split que es erroneo.

(si estas en windows, abre el archivo *test.out* con el bloc de notas)

Un saludo.